# Windows 10 keeps uninstalling my Creative X-fi drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers

Every day, or after 2 or 3 days my sound card stops working. If I look to Device manager the sound card is listed with a yellow question mark. The drivers are gone.
I have installed the drivers a few times now but it keeps happening again.
After installation of the drivers the sound works until Windows decides to uninstall it again.

My soundcard is a old Creative Xtreme Music using driver v2.30.4.
I am running Windows 10 x64 1511 build 10586.318

Answer (score 0):

There is a new driver for Windows 10 build 10586 available on their website [here](http://support.creative.com/Products/ProductDetails.aspx?catID=1&CatName=sound+blaster&prodID=14066&prodName=X-Fi+XtremeMusic). (v2.30.11)

Release Notes:

> What's New:
>
> •Fix installation issues on Windows 10  Build 10586.

Comment: Well when I install the 2.30.11 drivers the soundcard is not working. After the next reboot Creative auto update shows me that there is an update available. While installing the update I see in my task bar that there are devices being installed.  I'm going to wait untill it occurs again.

Comment: @com2ghz Be sure to let me know of the result.

Comment: Well I have replaced my motherboard and memory because of unexpected freezes and high CPU temps. My PC is more stable now, but sometimes still getting BSOD WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT. I have removed the soundcard now. I think windows is detecting that the hardware or the drivers are causing problems. I ll notify when this fixes my problem